# How could light from a TV screen refract when viewed through a helmet's transparent visor?

Tags: optics, polarization, birefringence

How could light from a TV screen refract when viewed through a helmet's  transparent visor?

[image]

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate. Of course the physics is the same, but this is specifically about what one can often see in reflected light from LCD displays. The other question does not have the nice photo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TV display is an lcd display, its light is polarized.

The helmet's visor is birefringent because of strains in the polymer material. That will rotate the plane of polarization, different for different wavelengths.

The reflection is different for different polarizations, it acts as the analyzer here.

The colors are not really the colors of a rainbow, but complementary colors of the primary colors. Where the red from the display gets extinguished you will see cyan. Where the blue is extinguished you see yellow. Where the green is missing you see magenta.

This phenomenon is indeed not due to refraction.

Edit: I took your photo and tried to show the origin of the colors. In three strips, the RGB channels are shown. And then one sees that the cyan bands occur where the red intensity is lowest. Etc.
[image: RGB decomposition]

Comment: I don't get it fully. If that is the case the strains should be disorderly. How come the colors VIBGYOR  appear so successively to neatly arrange themselves in that order of the dispersion spectrum ? Basically how does strain increase with color of light? Is the strain increasing uniformly as per some pattern?

Comment: @Narasimham In this case, the birefringence arose probably when the vizor was formed. Then polymer chains align a bit. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelasticity  The physics of interference fringes in thin films is different, but one sees the same kind of complementary colors:  https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Film_of_soap_interference_3_RGB.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the edit, seems to make sense (to me) now.

Answer (score -2):

It is very simple to understand
For rainbow formation we need white light , water droplet, and air
Here LED/LCD screen are designed by polariser which act like water droplet and helmet lid is polymer which is another medium where light can enter.
So here we got our light--> TV's screen(droplet) -->helmet another refrective medium and here we got VIBGYOR

LED / LCD stand for light emitting diode and liquid crystal display which dispers the light you can see rainbow on tv screen by 30° angle